# Preview last captured image from AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I want to use AVCaptureSession to capture images within my iOS App.
Based on the code from Apple's sample for AVCam https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html I tried to show a preview ImageView every time an image is captured.

```
// Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
        }
    }];
```

After capturing processImage is called

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [[self postButton] setEnabled:YES];
    [[self postButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[self cancelButton] setEnabled:YES];
    [[self cancelButton] setHidden:NO];

    _preview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [_preview setImage:image];

    _preview.hidden = NO;
}
```

But the ImageView is still unchanged/empty when it is displayed.

Can someone help me along?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
AVCaptureConnection *connection = [_currentOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[self _setOrientationForConnection:connection];

[_captureOutputPhoto captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection completionHandler:
^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    if (!imageDataSampleBuffer) {
        DLog(@"failed to obtain image data sample buffer");
        // return delegate error
        return;
    }

    if (error) {
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vision:capturedPhoto:error:)]) {
            [_delegate vision:self capturedPhoto:nil error:error];
        }
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *photoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *metadata = nil;

    // add photo metadata (ie EXIF: Aperture, Brightness, Exposure, FocalLength, etc)
    metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageDataSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
    if (metadata) {
        [photoDict setObject:metadata forKey:PBJVisionPhotoMetadataKey];
        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(metadata));
    } else {
        DLog(@"failed to generate metadata for photo");
    }

    // add JPEG and image data
    NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    if (jpegData) {
        // add JPEG
        [photoDict setObject:jpegData forKey:PBJVisionPhotoJPEGKey];

        // add image
        UIImage *image = [self _uiimageFromJPEGData:jpegData];
        if (image) {
            [photoDict setObject:image forKey:PBJVisionPhotoImageKey];
        } else {
            DLog(@"failed to create image from JPEG");
            // TODO: return delegate on error
        }

        // add thumbnail
        UIImage *thumbnail = [self _thumbnailJPEGData:jpegData];
        if (thumbnail) {
            [photoDict setObject:thumbnail forKey:PBJVisionPhotoThumbnailKey];
        } else {
            DLog(@"failed to create a thumnbail");
            // TODO: return delegate on error
        }

    } else {
        DLog(@"failed to create jpeg still image data");
        // TODO: return delegate on error
    }

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vision:capturedPhoto:error:)]) {
        [_delegate vision:self capturedPhoto:photoDict error:error];
    }

    // run a post shot focus
    [self performSelector:@selector(_focus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the trouble here is that completionHandler for captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection isn't being called on main thread. Try redispatching your call out to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
});
```

I also notice that you're never adding _preview as a subview of anything.